# cannot execute binary file processor and file 32 bit

Tags: 12.04, bash, xserver

I am running ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS based OS on my ARM based processor. I am not able to run an executable file. The name of my file is SerialSignals. When, I type,

```
./SerialSignals
```

I get

```
root@localhost:~/Desktop/gs/AppliMux/SerialSignals# ./SerialSignals
SerialSignals: cannot connect to X server
```

And when I type,

```
bash SerialSignals
```

this happens

```
root@localhost:~/Desktop/gs/AppliMux/SerialSignals# bash SerialSignals
SerialSignals: SerialSignals: cannot execute binary file
```

Following commands below for reference of 32 bit architecture ad file generated.

```
root@localhost:~/Desktop/gs/AppliMux/SerialSignals# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.12.0-xillinux-1.3 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 13 18:39:32 IST 2014 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

root@localhost:~/Desktop/gs/AppliMux/SerialSignals# file SerialSignals
SerialSignals: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0x175f32c78709e213111037c70910c661092a42ff, not stripped
```

Can anyone help me resolve this ? I even tried chmod. Still issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you are either

A: In an ssh session with your device

or

B: You do not currently have an X session

If you're running it via ssh, that won't work. Sorry.

If not, then run `startx` then open a terminal and run your program again.

Comment: Yes, I am running it via putty. My hardware (ARM controller) uses a serial port to connect . so, running it on serial port 4. My hardware doesn't have GUI support.  Is there any way of running this code without the GUI ? What about running in the background using ./SerialSignals & .

Comment: Can your device connect to the internet?

Comment: Yes. But my device doesn't have a video port (HDMI<,DVI,etc)

Comment: Ok, then run `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver lxde lxde-session xinit xorg -y` then run `tightvncserver; tightvncserver`. Then, install a VNC client on your PC. Open said VNC client and type `012.345.678.910:1` (Replace `012.345.678.910` with the IP of your board)